# I'm I doing something wrong here? I am trying to create my first azure aks but the service principal isn't working or available, any help pls?

Tags: terraform

Here is my **azuread.tf** file
[azuread.tf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXNvj.png)

here is my **cluster.tf** file
[cluster.tf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qalwk.png)

I'm having this error when I execute terraform apply.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qalwk.png)

Comment: Hi Louis, the link for cluster.tf refers to the same screen-shot as the error message. Also, please add all the content as text into your question, instead of linking to screenshots.

Comment: thanks adp i resolve this by creating a service principal on azure cli